# Capture file download

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer and crawling on a page that sends a `.csv` when done in Chrome, Chrome downloads a `.csv` while the main page remains open.

How would i capture the `.csv` file in `Puppeteer`?

I checked browser.pages() but it does not seem to increase.

Comment: Already opened issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/299